# WPF Binding in Style

Tags: wpf, binding, styles

I'm trying to set together a simple `TextBox` with some watermark text in the `Background`. My code is based on the example from [Philip Patrick's blog](http://blog.stpworks.com/archive/2008/04/23/wpf-adding-text-as-a-background-of-textbox-or-combobox.aspx).

I'm trying to tweak it so that the text displayed in the background is retrieved from the `ToolTip` property on the `TextBox`.

Currently this works:

```
<TextBox ToolTip="Type a name here...">
            <TextBox.Background>
                <VisualBrush TileMode="None" Opacity="0.4" Stretch="None" AlignmentX="Left">
                    <VisualBrush.Visual>
                        <TextBlock FontStyle="Italic" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TextBox}}, Path=ToolTip}"/>
                    </VisualBrush.Visual>
                </VisualBrush>
            </TextBox.Background>
        </TextBox>
```

That displays the `ToolTip` text in the `Background` of the `TextBox`.

But if I move part of the code out to a Resource Style the binding no longer gets the `ToolTip` info from the `TextBox`:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="WatermarkBackground" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <VisualBrush TileMode="None" Opacity="0.4" Stretch="None" AlignmentX="Left">
                        <VisualBrush.Visual>
                            <TextBlock FontStyle="Italic" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TextBox}}, Path=ToolTip}"/>
                        </VisualBrush.Visual>
                    </VisualBrush>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <TextBox ToolTip="Type your name here..." Style="{StaticResource WatermarkBackground}"/>
```

Any tips here?

Comment: Could you use a template instead of a Style so you can use {Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=ToolTip}?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cann't access TextBox the way you are trying, your TextBlock is not in the visual hierarchy of your TextBox. So it is not able to find the TextBox. You can try with Watermarked TextBox.
[Check this](http://edgeug.net/blogs/nondestructive/archive/2009/01/02/wpf-textbox-with-watermark.aspx) for a Sample of Watermarked TextBox.